# Keras generator and fit_generator, how to build the generator to avoid 'function shape' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a generator for Keras to be able to load my dataset images since it's a bit big for my ram.

I built the generator like this:

```
# import the necessary packages
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

#loading
path_to_txt = "/content/test/leafsnap-dataset/leafsnap-dataset- 
images_improved.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_txt ,sep='\t')
arr = np.array(df)
#epochs and steps:
NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES = 0
NUM_EPOCHS = 30

def image_generator(arr, bs, mode="train", aug=None):
  while True:
    images = []
    labels = []
    for row in arr:
      if len(images) < bs:
        img = (cv2.resize(cv2.imread("/content/test/leafsnap-dataset/" + 
        row[0]),(224,224)))
        images.append(img)
        labels.append([row[2]])
        NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES += 1
      else:
        break


  if aug is not None:
    (images, labels) = next(aug.flow(np.array(images),labels, 
     batch_size=bs))

  obj = OneHotEncoder()
  values = obj.fit_transform(labels).toarray()

  yield (np.array(images), labels)
```

I then call fit_generator from a Sequential model (the cnn worked until I got OOM error)

```
#create the augmentation function:
 aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20, zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

#create the generator:
gen = image_generator(arr, bs = 32, mode = "train", aug = aug)

history = model.fit_generator(image_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES,
    epochs = NUM_EPOCHS)
```

And from here, I get this error:

```
# Create generator from NumPy or EagerTensor Input.
--> 377   num_samples = int(nest.flatten(data)[0].shape[0])
378   if batch_size is None:
379     raise ValueError('You must specify `batch_size`')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Firstly your generator function is not memory efficient. Because you load all images at first. You should iterate over image files and inside loop yield np.array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two major errors here.

Firstly your generator function is not memory efficient. Because you load all images at first (while loop). You should iterate over image files and inside loop yield np.array of image with label.

Secondly you pass generator function name to fit_generator when you should use its returned object - gen.

Comment: Oh god, didn't see the error between function and object name after a hundred times reading the code. As for the optimization, yes I'm new to the concept, I will optimize it now. Thank you.

Comment: I assume that yield statement is inside some loop? If it's not this generator will be the same memory efficient as without generator

Comment: Actually I think it is not inside the loop, because you don't loop through all the images, but only until you reach bs size. But my implementation is wrong anyways.